# Closest thing to reagents cursor in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clojurescript, reagent

I have used the [cursor](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-cookbook/tree/master/basics/cursors) concept from reagent in previous projects and i think it is a nice middle ground between manually dealing with state in component local state vs full blown redux

I've come across various libraries that have taken a lot of inspiration from Clojure (such as ramda) but I haven't seen a port of this idea.

At first, it seems like ramda lens is a good start but I haven't managed to properly replicate the behaviour. Is there a pure js version that I can use, preferably with good integration with ramda.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ImmutableJS has a number of functions to manipulate deeply nested maps, much like in Clojure, and even a `getIn` function much like Clojure's own `get-in`: https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js#nested-structures